# If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Riemann integrable and $f(x)≤h(x)≤g(x)$, must $h(x)$ be Riemann integrable? (Repost)

Tags: real-analysis

What if we added some assumptions that the integral of $f$ and $g$ from $a$ to $b$ are equal? Must $h(x)$ be Riemann integrable?

Comment: Without the assumption, certainly not: on your domain of definition, let $f$ be the constant function equal to $0$, $g$ the constant function equal to $1$, $h$ the indicator function on the rationals.

Answer (score 3):

For a given partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ and a function $t(x)$ use the shorthand $t_L,t_U$ for the lower and upper sums of $t$ for the partition $P$. Then from $f\le h \le g$ you get
$$f_L \le h_L \le h_R \le g_R.$$
Thus if the integrals of $f,g$ are equal to say $A$, on taking the limit over partitions $P$ whose mesh goes to zero, we get $h_L,h_R \to A$ since the outside sums $f_L,g_R$ both go to $A$ because of the assumption that the integrals of $f,g$ exist and are equal to $A$.